# Stop datetime from autofilling time to 12:00

Tags: lightning, administration, datetime

In lightning if you choose date first the time will autofill to 12:00.

Is there anyway to stop this?

Our users should specify time, but routine takes over after some time and almost every datetime is noon in database.

My only idea is to block saving action if time is exactly 12:00, but this have an obvious downside.

Comment: Can you share the html and js code? As the LWC Date time will accept the current time if the user didn't change the time. You can not erase the value in the time field, you can either set the value to current time.

Comment: @MukulMahawariya You need to ask Salesforce directly for any code ;). 
Maybe I didn't make it clear enough, but I meant standard fields editor, like on record edit page.